# Deploy Angular Application in Cloud Foundry

Tags: angular, deployment, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my Angular application in Cloud Foundry.

After testing locally with `ng serve` I confirmed my application is running well.

Here are the steps I did to deploy in CF:

1. In app directory executed `ng build --prod` which created `dist` folder"
2. Copied the dist folder into other directory and created `manifest.yml` file with following contents: (yml file and dist folder is on the same directory)

   ```
   applications:

   name: deploy-ng4

   memory: 128M

     buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git

     path: dist
   ```
3. Executed

   ```
   cf push deploy-ng4 -m 128M -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
   ```
4. CF logs shows deployed service is running, I haven't seen any errors.
5. When I tried browsing the URL which listed in `cf apps` for this deployed application, it's showing 403 - Forbidden.

Comment: I've deployed the results of an `ng build --prod` the same way successfully, so you'll have to provide more information to replicate. Can you just get a single `index.html` serving correctly? Also note that there's no point having a manifest if you're going to pass the content again as flags to `cf push`, or vice versa.

Comment: Please double-check the content of the manifest file - that doesn't look like correct YAML for an application config, which is maybe why you needed the push flags. Also note you'll a Staticfile and pushstate routing, see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but *don't* use the master branch of a buildpack.  You'll never know what you're going to get.  Either use the buildpack that is installed on you platform (i.e. `cf buildpacks`) or use a release of the buildpack.  Example using latest release at the time of writing from Github:  `-b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git#v1.4.27`.  Example using system buildpack:  `-b staticfile_buildpack`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong buildpack.
Cloud Foundry has built-in support for NodeJS, thus if your app contains package.json file, you can issue the following command:

```
cf push <APP> -m <Memory> .
```

NodeJS buildpack is open source and hosted at: `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack`, so you could alo customize the buildpack and push it like:

```
cf push <APP> -m <Memory> -b 'https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack'
```

Check also `cf help push` in order to see all parameter options etc.

BTW, if NodeJS has version mismatch with the default version in the buildpack, you have to set the version number explicitly in `package.json`.  [See the document](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html#specify-a-node.js-version).

Answer (score 1):

Probably already solved, but for people facing similar issue: Check `outputPath` property in  `angular.json` file. For this case it has to be:

```
"outputPath": "dist"
```

I faced similar issue with PCF deployment. I generated my Angular application with IntelliJ Idea and it has appended the name of project to `outputPath`. Then I got exactly 403 - Forbidden accessing URL provided by PCF for the service, since correct URL was with `/projectname` appendix.